# Write Parent Package Variables to a file

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

How can I write `Parent Package variables` to a file (or somehow know what the values are) when executing a SSIS package? (Variables like: System::PackageName)

I also have to say that I'm new in SSIS packages and workflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a derived column transformation to your solution and add in the system variables from the Variables dropdown list[image]

You can then use this to output to a flatfile/database/Excel etc